# How to convert an Array of array to array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, variables

I have a problem when converting an array of array to array 
when I debug a variable named `$todaysdata`, It shows below output,

```
             Array
                 (
                   [0] => Array
                        (
                           [Requestcard] => Array
                             (
                                 [id] => 954
                                 [userprofile_id] => 14
                                 [userprofile_name] => Syed Imran
                                 [sex] => male

                              )

                         )

                )
```

But actually i want the output in in the given format

```
                           Array
                               (
                                 [Requestcard] => Array
                                    (
                                      [id] => 954
                                      [userprofile_id] => 14
                                      [userprofile_name] => Syed Imran
                                      [sex] => male

                                     )

                               )
```

If anybody knows. Please help me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Just show me your code where u r printing the array,....

Comment: This is not CakePHP question, it is primary subject from PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `array_shift`

```
array_shift($array)
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using `array_shift` in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for solving the example that you've given would be similar to:

```
$result_array = $original_array[0];
```

If you have multiple arrays to move up, you might want to consider PHP's [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.